# Use public Tor nodes as a proxy for your own use

Tags: proxy

I want to try to use some Tor nodes as a proxy for personal use, based on this I think I need to enter the node's public ip address and its port in the proxy settings. How right am I and is this scenario realistic?

I am using https://www.dan.me.uk/tornodes to search for nodes.

I've tried connecting several of these nodes as proxies through Proxifier, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how Tor relays work. They only proxy traffic sent to them from a Tor client (ex: web browser -> tor client -> tor network). You cannot set an IP/port for a relay directly in your application's proxy settings.